# Can't update value of list element in python

Tags: python, list

Can someone explain why the below mentioned behavior happens, in debug mode, why cannot I update a list element value:

[image]

I don't get, what I'm doing wrong?
My code:

```
 if request.method == 'GET':
        coordinates = mongo_harassments_utils.get_geolocated({})
        count =  coordinates.count()
        for i in range(coordinates.count()):
            first = coordinates[i]["story"]
            coordinates[i]["story"] = "Test"
            second = coordinates[i]["story"]
```

Comment: @idjaw I did that only for reasons that in that picture you can see the values on debug mode

Comment: @Lafexlos as u can see in the picture, u see that even after I assign a string value "Test" in coordinates[i]['story'] the value still remain the same

Comment: Yeah, I saw that later and that's why I removed my comment but seems like I was slow.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `coordinates` is not a list, but a `pymongo.cursor.Cursor`. You need to explicitly coerce it to a list for the code to work:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    coordinates = list(mongo_harassments_utils.get_geolocated({}))
    count = len(coordinates)
    for i in range(len(coordinates)):
        first = coordinates[i]["story"]
        coordinates[i]["story"] = "Test"
        second = coordinates[i]["story"]
```

Also, explicit indexing is often considered an anti-pattern in Python. For your case `enumerate` is perfectly applicable

```
for i, coordinate in enumerate(coordinates):
    first = coordinate["story"]
    coordinate["story"] = "Test"
    second = coordinate["story"]
```

Note that with `enumerate` you no longer need to make `coordinates` a list.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is that it's not a list. Not all iterables are lists, and in your particular situation "coordinates" looks like a mongodb cursor.